# Setting a timeout for a request method

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to set up a timeout for a request method that checks username availability. When the user types in a username and presses a button, the `checkUsername` method is called. My code is not working because the code inside `Timeout(5.0){}` is never executed and `timeout` never gets the value `false`. I know this is not the best way to do it but I wanted to give it a try and wonder if this can be modified in some way or do I need a different approach?

```
var timeout: Bool = false

func usernameAvailable(username: String) -> String{
    let response: String!
    response = Server.checkUsername(username!)

    Timeout(5.0){
      self.timeout = true
    }

    while(!timeout){
        if(response != nil){
           return response
        }
    }
    return "Timeout"
}
```

The `Timeout.swift` class looks like this and is working

```
class Timeout: NSObject{

private var timer: NSTimer?
private var callback: (Void -> Void)?

init(_ delaySeconds: Double, _ callback: Void -> Void){
    super.init()
    self.callback = callback
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(delaySeconds),
        target: self, selector: "invoke", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func invoke(){
    self.callback?()
    // Discard callback and timer.
    self.callback = nil
    self.timer = nil
}

func cancel(){
    self.timer?.invalidate()
    self.timer = nil
}
}
```

Comment: You should describe how `checkUsername` is implemented. The refactoring of this code starts there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the `Timeout` block will never run because the timer will fire on the on the main thread, but you're blocking the main thread with your `while` loop.

You have another issue here, that you're calling `Server.checkUsername(username!)` and returning that result, which would suggest that this must be a synchronous call (which is not good). So, this is also likely blocking the main thread there. It won't even try to start the `Timeout` logic until `checkUsername` returns.

There are kludgy fixes for this, but in my opinion, this begs for a very different pattern. One should never write code that has a spinning `while` loop that is polling some completion status. It is much better to adopt asynchronous patterns with `completionHandler` closures. But without more information on what `checkUsername` is doing, it's hard to get more specific.

But, ideally, if your `checkUsername` is building a `NSMutableURLRequest`, just specify `timeoutInterval` for that and then have the `NSURLSessionTask` completion block check for `NSError` with `domain` of `NSURLErrorDomain` and a code of `NSURLError.TimedOut`. You also probably want to cancel the prior request if it's already running.

```
func startRequestForUsername(username: String, timeout: NSTimeInterval, completionHandler: (Bool?, NSError?) -> ()) -> NSURLSessionTask {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: ...)  // configure your request however appropriate for your web service
    request.timeoutInterval = timeout            // but make sure to specify timeout

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            guard data != nil && error == nil else {
                completionHandler(nil, error)
                return
            }

            let usernameAvailable = ...  // parse the boolean success/failure out of the `data` however appropriate
            completionHandler(usernameAvailable, nil)
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    return task
}
```

And you can then use it like so:

```
private weak var previousTask: NSURLSessionTask?

func checkUsername(username: String) {
    // update the UI to say that we're checking the availability of the user name here, e.g. 

    usernameStatus.text = "Checking username availability..."

    // now, cancel prior request (if any)

    previousTask?.cancel()

    // start new request

    let task = startRequestForUsername(username, timeout: 5) { usernameAvailable, error in
        guard usernameAvailable != nil && error == nil else {
            if error?.domain == NSURLErrorDomain && error?.code == NSURLError.TimedOut.rawValue {
                // everything is cool, the task just timed out
            } else if error?.domain == NSURLErrorDomain && error?.code != NSURLError.Cancelled.rawValue {
                // again, everything is cool, the task was cancelled
            } else {
                // some error other  happened, so handle that as you see fit
                // but the key issue that if it was `.TimedOut` or `.Cancelled`, then don't do anything
            }
            return
        }

        if usernameAvailable! {
            // update UI to say that the username is available

            self.usernameStatus.text = "Username is available"
        } else {
            // update UI to say that the username is not available

            self.usernameStatus.text = "Username is NOT available"
        }
    }

    // save reference to this task

    previousTask = task
}
```

By the way, if you do this sort of graceful, asynchronous processing of requests, you can also increase the timeout interval (e.g. maybe 10 or 15 seconds). We're not freezing the UI, so we can do whatever we want, and not artificially constrain the time allowed for the request.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are trying to do and it would make more sense to use an existing framework unless you really need/want to write your own networking code.

I would suggest instead to use the timeoutInterval support in an `NSURLRequest` along with a completion handler on `NSURLSession` to achieve the solution that you are seeking.

A timeout of the server response can be handled in the completion handler of something like an `NSURLSessionDataTask`.

Here is a working example to help get you started that retrieves data from the iTunes Store to illustrate how your timeout could be handled:

```
let timeout = 5 as NSTimeInterval
let searchTerm = "philip+glass"
let url = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(searchTerm)")
let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!,
                                         cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData,
                                         timeoutInterval: timeout)
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
let task: NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in
        if response == nil {
            print("Timeout")
        } else {
            print(String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        }
    }
)

task.resume()
```

If you reduce the timeout interval to something short, you can force the timeout to happen.